# Elsa workflow integration

Tags: webapi, elsa-workflows, blazer

I have blazer web application which is Front-end.
On another side I have web API from where my all the database operations are performed,
For all the operation, I have developed web api which can be call from blazer application, both are in different projects solutions,

And can also can be hosted in different servers.

Right now I have form in my blazer application and once I save it, it will call the webapi and save the data in database.

Now I want to integrate the Elsa workflow to save form via some approval workflow.

Also my web api have the token base authentication,

So I have created and install All the Elsa server related package in webapi project, and Elsa dashboard related nuget package in blazer project. So I need help for below.

1. My Elsa dashboard ui can not be connected to the Elsa server. Asking for authentication.
2. How can I integrate Elsa workflow for my form so that it can save via some approval process.

Please can any one help me with this?